# Is there a way to send a phone call to a phone number without start the dialer Voice application using react native?

Tags: react-native, gsm, phone-call, smartphone, sim-card

We are making an electronic device with a SIM Card included in it. Then, when we make a call to a certain phone number associated with this SimCard, that triggers some actions in the device.

Now I want to develop a react native phone application to send the phone call request "in the background" when a button is tapped in this app.

Are there any ways to do this? I don't want to run the installed phone app/dialer app, because we do not intend to talk someone, but only trigger an event.

I've been looking for a solution but the react-native modules working with phone calls (example: react-native-communications) are not very clear concerning this.

If a solution using react native weren't available I accept other ideas about how to implement this requirement (angular, or using an intermediate server with node/PHP/Java/etc..)

Thank you.